# Examples of IQbservable

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, system.reactive

I am trying to come up with some good examples of [`IQbservable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.iqbservable%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) usage and thought I'd ask if anyone has used it yet, or has any ideas for how it might be used or abused?

**EDIT** This (`IQbservable`) is not a typo! (See comments)

Comment: To those making modifications, [IQbservable](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Bart-De-Smet-Observations-on-IQbservable-The-Dual-of-IQueryable/).  Seems it's not a typo.

Comment: Wow, I love how the question specifically said "(Not IObservable)" and then one editor removed that part, and then another changed it to "IObserable". Read history you damned fools!

Comment: You could also blame MS for such a wrong-looking name...(http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/rx/thread/641ed699-4a24-4093-a0d1-b00b486627d2)

Comment: @notJim That was mainly a case of multiple people editing and submitting changes at the same time, thus overwriting another's changes.

Comment: There's not much info out there on IQObservable - and the mistaken 'corrections' to IObservable are confirmation of this. For this reason the close of this question as 'not constructive' is not appropriate here.

Comment: @FrepD-Oronge Vote to reopen, if you like ... I agree, and am hoping that more answers are added over time. :)

Comment: @FrepD-Oronge That there's not a lot of info out there doesn't make the question any more constructive.  It's a polling/list question, and that style of question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow's Q/A format.  This question has no business being reopened.  If you would like to see something like this discussed, it would need to be on another site that is better suited to such questions.

Comment: @Servy Given the context, it's not polling, it's a legitimate question because there isn't a billion possible answers - it has a certain utility that hasn't been fleshed out yet.  This is totally unlike asking for "good examples of WPF applications" or the ilk.  YMMV.

Comment: @RichardHein That's *exactly* what it's like, because there *are* a billion possible answers.  Just because someone hasn't written them yet doesn't mean they can't.  Over time the question would collect more and more answers without bound.  The fact that there aren't a *huge* number of people capable of posting answers at this time doesn't automatically make the question acceptable.

Comment: @Servy ok, give me one that hasn't been given.

Comment: @Servy Unfortunately I can't vote to re-open, I don't have the rep. Perhaps you could for me, thanks

Comment: @FrepD-Oronge a) The question is open currently b) You can flag the post if you think it should be reopened c) I don't the post should be open.  I feel (strongly) that it should be closed.

Comment: Despite the mods following their little script and closing the question, this is still google result #1 and I'm still interested in finding examples like the original poster. Can anyone point any out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just like IQueryable lets you not double-evaluate an expression when you chain operations (since you can fetch out the underlying Expression), IQbservable has the same advantages. You can get the complete observable expression, so that you can make custom Rx implementations (just like you can make Linq-to-SQL, Linq-to-XML, Linq-to-Twitter, etc).

Some ideas for IQbservable implementations? How about:

- Node.js style single-threaded IQbservable, no locks, only a runloop
- Rx-to-ServiceBus, implementing blocking operations and Schedulers as separate machines and waiting on the results instead of using simple locks and Task items

Answer (score 6):

Bart De Smet (member of the Cloud Computability team, responsible for Rx) has posted the source code for an IQbservable provider.  The details and link to the code are available at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/d459291a-4245-45ba-8888-35e07f7cf5b2.

Answer (score 1):

The Rxx team has released an alpha of a TCP IQbservable implementation.  Looks very nice:  http://rxx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TCP%20Qbservable%20Provider